Can someone here recommend books for physics?
basically I want books at advanced High-School level that make stuff easier to understand as well as make them interesting and i want them to be relevant to a level physics CIE  which is Cambridge international examination
1 Physical quantities and units
2 Kinematics
3 Dynamics
4 Forces, density and pressure
5 Work, energy and power
6 Deformation of solids
7 Waves
8 Superposition
9 Electricity
10 D.C. circuits
11 Particle physics
these are the topics i wanna learn about
